# Force redirect HTTPS with www

Tags: apache, amazon-elb

In AWS ELB terminates SSL to someone who explicitly types ‘https://example.com‘ but the connection of the poor bloke who types ‘http://example.com‘ is left unsecured.

How to redirect to https://example.com to https://www.example.com?

Answer (score 1):

I have done mistake while generating SSL certificate on AWS Certificate Manager.

Now I have added domain names with example.com,*example.com, and www.example.com

Comment: So why didn't you upvote my solution and mark it as solved?

Comment: We need to add domain names while generate the key.

Comment: For example.  example.com,*example.com, and www.example.com

Comment: That issue is not part of the question. The question is about redirects.

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/sovereign/sovereign/issues/524
Put this in the configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com
    RedirectMatch permanent "^(.*)" "https://www.example.com$1"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: try debugging it with "curl -i"

Comment: curl -i https://example.com/
curl: (51) Unable to communicate securely with peer: requested domain name does not match the server's certificate.